# Android noobie with form to make url

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I've fingers on my teeths with Java and Android. Normaly i code with Python, it easier and easier !

Java never let me do anything, or only in a unique method that i never know :(
So the only code working is copy-paste and it's hard to customize...

So, i've a simple editable text and a button, when i click on it, i go to an url. The button works : i can open my webview.
But i want to make the url with the editText and i can't :(

See that :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

 // Add Click listeners for all buttons
    final EditText Login = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.entry);
    View firstButton = findViewById(R.id.ok);
    firstButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {

    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.ok:
            Intent j = new Intent(this, Webscreen.class);
            j.putExtra(com.tatai.froyo.Webscreen.URL, 
                "http://192.168.1.12/index2.php");
            startActivity(j);
        break;
    }
```

So, how can i have the login edittext to make the url like http://192.168.1.12/index2.php?log=toto 
... where toto may is get with the login edittext.

Impossible to read a global var on the onclick, i'm lost ! :(

i trid that on the onclick listner :
String logDetail = Login.getText().toString();
but it can't see Login, it's out ! : undeclared

Comment: Login.getText().toString() will get you started.

Comment: I think objects are not for my brain... those are too much isolated by the other code and it's to hard to make communication with objects. I prefer unique centralised and linear code !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on your code, TRy this,

```
  public void onClick(View v) 
     {      
      switch(v.getId())
        {         
         case R.id.ok:

          String logDetail = Login.getText().toString();

           Intent j = new Intent(this, Webscreen.class);
           j.putExtra(com.tatai.froyo.Webscreen.URL,"http://192.168.1.12/index2.php?log="+logDetail);
          startActivity(j);     
           break;     
          }
```

EDIT:

```
 EditText Login;

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {     
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
 setContentView(R.layout.main);   
 // Add Click listeners for all buttons    

  Login = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.entry);     

 View firstButton = findViewById(R.id.ok);     

  firstButton.setOnClickListener(this); 
  }  

  public void onClick(View v) 
     {      
      switch(v.getId())
        {         
         case R.id.ok:

          String logDetail = Login.getText().toString();

           Intent j = new Intent(this, Webscreen.class);

j.putExtra(com.tatai.froyo.Webscreen.URL,"http://192.168.1.12/index2.php?log="+logDetail);
          startActivity(j);     
           break;     
          }
```

Comment: Thanks for u'r help. i'd tried that but it said : Login undeclared

Comment: look at my edited answer. you should declare edittext in this way so you dont get error.

Comment: It works ! great thanks, i didn't know we could do that :) i've not enough reputation to give you a point, sorry.